# Create a list by selecting 1 element from each list (prolog)

Tags: prolog

I have a list that contains lists. 
I want to create a list of permutation.

Example:

```
generate_perm([[3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2]], P).
P = [[3,1,1], [3,2,1], [3,3,1], [3,4,1], [3,1,2], [3,2,2], [3,3,2], [3,4,2]];
no
```

So the output lists: n-th element is an element of the n-th list from the input lists. 
What I've already tried: using member, and findall but I'm stuck. Since I'm new to prolog I always think imperatively.

My code so far for giving 1 solution:

```
generate_perm([],_).
generate_perm([H|Tl], Perm):- member(M, H), append(Perm, [M], Perm2),
                              generate_perm(Tl, Perm2).
```

Debugging of this:

```
| ?- generate_perm([[3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2]], P).
 #      1      1 Call: member(_4961,[3]) ? 
 #      1      1 Exit: member(3,[3]) ? 
 #      2      1 Call: generate_perm([[1,2,3,4],[1,2]],[3]) ? 
 #      3      2 Call: member(_56173,[1,2,3,4]) ? 
?#      3      2 Exit: member(1,[1,2,3,4]) ? 
 #      4      2 Call: generate_perm([[1,2]],[3,1]) ? 
 #      5      3 Call: member(_138349,[1,2]) ? 
?#      5      3 Exit: member(1,[1,2]) ? 
 #      6      3 Call: generate_perm([],[3,1,1]) ? 
 #      6      3 Exit: generate_perm([],[3,1,1]) ? 
?#      4      2 Exit: generate_perm([[1,2]],[3,1]) ? 
?#      2      1 Exit: generate_perm([[1,2,3,4],[1,2]],[3]) ? 
P = [] ?
```

So the answer is there (Call: generate_perm([],[3,1,1]), here the answer is [3,1,1]), but it gives me an empty list, and I can't figure out why. 
And another step where I need help is I don't have an idea how to get all the solutions in 1 list.

Comment: Think what the `generate_perm` will be of an empty list, a list with one sublist, and a list with more than one sublist.

Comment: Sorry, can you be a little more specific? I didn't understand your idea.

Comment: stuck where? please edit the question and add your code, the sample query you're trying to run, and Prolog's response.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my first try, but now I tried again and uploaded my code.

Comment: @Goba: what if you use `append/3` in *reverse*?

Comment: How do you mean in reverse?
If at the closing term I use this:  generate_perm([], Perm):-write(Perm).
It writes the result correctly.

Comment: @Goba: use `append(Perm2, [M], Perm)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like said, "imperative thinking" usually does not go very well with Prolog. You should think in terms of (recursive) definitions.

For example we can say that the `crossprod/2` where the first list is empty yields one solution: the empty list, so we can specify this as:

```
crossprod([], []).
```

now we still need to come up with an inductive case: given we can generate the permutation for a list of *n-1* elements, then how should we generate the permutation for a list of *n* elements (with *n≥0*).

For such lists, we have the first element (the "head") here that head is a list (since the first argument should be a list of lists). So we can use `member/2` to take an element of the *sub*list, that element will be the *head* (first item) of the result list, we then pass the tail (remaining sublists) recursively to `crossprod/2` to generate the tail of the result, like:

```
crossprod([H|T], [X|R]) :-
    member(X, H),
    crossprod(T, R).
```

or in full, this gives:

```
crossprod([], []).
crossprod([H|T], [X|R]) :-
    member(X, H),
    crossprod(T, R).
```

So now we can generate items of the "cross product" of the given list of "sets", like:

```
?- crossprod([[3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2]], P).
P = [3, 1, 1] ;
P = [3, 1, 2] ;
P = [3, 2, 1] ;
P = [3, 2, 2] ;
P = [3, 3, 1] ;
P = [3, 3, 2] ;
P = [3, 4, 1] ;
P = [3, 4, 2].
```

If we then want to generate a list of these (which is rather odd, typically it is better to generate the answers independently), we can use `findall/3`:

generate_perm(S, R) :-
    findall(Ri, crossprod(S, Ri), R).

and then we obtain the list of cross-products, like:

```
?- generate_perm([[3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2]], P).
P = [[3, 1, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 2], [3, 3, 1], [3, 3, 2], [3, 4|...], [3|...]].
```